# Using $.post and passing return function as variable with additional parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main post function that I use for all my post calls:

```
function post_json(post_string, response_handler) {
    //
    // do logging and other things with post string
    //
    $.post(post_string,{},response_handler,'json');
}
```

I then will use this call in various pages:

```
post_json(post_url, handler_generic);
```

The handler_generic function is this:

```
function handler_generic(json) {       
    var success = json.success;
    var success_verbiage = json.success_verbiage;
    // do lots of stuff here   
}
```

This works perfectly.

What I want to do is have a function like this:

```
function handler_generic_with_extra(json, unique_id) {       
    var success = json.success;
    var success_verbiage = json.success_verbiage;
    // do lots of stuff here and now do it with the 
    // unique id  
}
```

I figured these would not work,  and they dont:

```
 post_json(appended_post_string, handler_generic_with_extra( the_unique_id));

 post_json(appended_post_string, handler_generic_with_extra( json, the_unique_id));
```

Without creating a new post_json function to handle these cases is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure:

```
post_json(appended_post_string,function(json){return handler_generic_with_extra( json, the_unique_id); });
```

Comment: I thik you'd just need to pass in json argument to the closure function
`post_json(appended_post_string,function(json){return handler_generic_with_extra( json, the_unique_id); });`